# Hide select if when don´t found any results

Tags: angularjs

I have a select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>
```

I try to hide select if I don´t have options with `ng-hide` as:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos " ng-hide="item.Catalogos == 0"></select>
```

or with `ng-show` as:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-show="Catalogos" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

But no one works, it still showing up, can anyone help me there?

> Note: I found an issue, if I debbug select with chrome or firefox I
>   get a default option as:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

Is it possible to skip this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the length of catalogos

```
<select class="form-control" ng-show="Catalogos.length>0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

Or you need to convert it to boolean

```
<select class="form-control" ng-show="!!Catalogos" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

Same process can be followed for ng-hide

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

Or

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="!Catalogos" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-hide` should be using `item.Catalogos.length`:

```
ng-hide="item.Catalogos.length == 0"
```

or

```
ng-hide="!item.Catalogos"
```

Comment: first one don´t works, second one hide option but if I have options it hide it too

Comment: Please post a (a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. If the object you're looking for is Catalogos instead of item.Catalogos it would be `ng-hide="!Catalogos"`